# Array to matrix

Tags: arrays, matrix, maxima

I am trying to find a way to convert a 41x41 array into a matrix in maxima.
I tried `aa1:matrix([aa]);`
If I try `matrixp(aa1)` it yields true but the matrix only contains the first value.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC Maxima arrays are [hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), so the order is not as firm as with matrices. That aside it seems it should be possible with some knowledge of how the array was generated and `genmatrix`, see the fifth [faq entry](http://cadadr.org/maxima/faq.html#Matrices_and_Linear_Algebra).

So if the array is generated like this:

```
(%i1) for i thru 4 do for j thru 4 do A[i,j]: i+j$
```

We have:

```
(%i2) listarray(A);
(%o2)   [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 7, 8]
(%i3) arrayinfo(A);
(%o3)   [hashed, 2, [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [4, 4]]
```

`A` can be converted to a 4x4 matrix like this:

```
(%i4) genmatrix(A,4,4);
        [ 2  3  4  5 ]
        [            ]
        [ 3  4  5  6 ]
(%o4)   [            ]
        [ 4  5  6  7 ]
        [            ]
        [ 5  6  7  8 ]
```

Comment: When I tried this I got a note that expression was too long to display.

'(%i901) aa1:genmatrix(aa,41,41)
 << Expression too long to display! >>'

When I checked it had made aa1 a matrix but several of the values were missing and instead just had aa1 sub 21,21.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error, even with an array of 410x410. Can you make a minimal example that has this error?

Comment: There was an error in my for loop that was creating problems. It works now thanks do much for the help.

I am now using maxima to find the eigenvalues of this matrix and it takes a very long time. On the order of an hour. Mathematica can solve the eigenvalues in about a minute. Does maxima have trouble handling matrices of this size?

Comment: @user1558881: The way to say thanks around here is to upvote useful answers and accept the correct one. The efficiency issue you're having sounds a bit odd, but it's hard to comment without a reproducible example. I suggest making such an example and posting it as a new question on Stackoverflow or send it to the Maxima mailing list.